# Using the Deployment Toolkit to detect openjdk under Ubuntu?

Tags: deployment, java

I'm using deployJava.js to detect and redirect for java compatibility. Now, however, I've noticed that deployJava.js does NOT detect openjdk. Is there a modified version of this file that does this? I'm digging through the script right now to attempt to hack in a fix, but it would be nice if this was an already solved problem.

Linkage:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web plugin FOR openjdk. Such is not provided by default. Try icedtea6-plugin.

Comment: As a side note, openjdk is spotty at best. If you can just support the sun plugin, DO IT.